# Is there a way for vscode to ignore .classpath but still recognize it as a java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code, classpath

I have a project that have been worked on eclipse by my coworker, they have it on git and have the `.classpath` and `.project` files on the repository.

I usually use Visual Studio Code and i wanted to use it for the java project as well.

The problem is that the `.classpath` contains classpathentrys that have been configured with the eclipse **Java Build Path** and contains all the external `Jars` that we need and also the `JRE`.

The thing is that the `JRE` is found without any problem in **org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER**, but all the other **org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY** can't be found.

The `.classpath` also contains a output path that uses the **Linked ressources** of eclipse and can't be find as well.

Is there a way to tell VS Code what each classpathentry path actually is? a sort of override ?

I know that we can specify the `java.project.referencedLibraries` in the `settings.json` and I did that but if i keep the `.classpath` the referencedLibraries are ignored on my project.

Even if i delete the `.classpath` and `.project` files VS Code seem to fail to recognize that it is a **java** project, so I'm a bit stuck here.

Any help would be appreciated,
don't hesitate to ask for more informations if needed

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should not rely on ODE specific files to build a java project. Use maven or cradle instead.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer thanks for your answer but i have no problem with the build, we use a ant task for this and it's working fine. The problem is with vscode not finding imports because it want to use the .classpath but do not understand it.
taht's why i would want it to be ginored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to make this work !

The way i did it was renaming the .classpath and .project files so that the project is "unmanaged".
Then vscode tell me that it's not a java project anymore, so i added the sourcepaths in settings.json like this :

```json
"java.project.sourcePaths":["."]
```

and then added all the libraries in "java.project.referencedLibraries" in settings.json, i waited for all of the libs to import and then it works !

I used the git update-index --assume-unchanged  for both .project and .classpath so that i don't delete it for my coworkers and kept the files in case i need to open it in eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a gitignore file?
[https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-what-is-it-and-how-to-add-to-repo/#:~:text=gitignore%20file%20is%20a%20text,all%20of%20your%20Git%20repositories](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-what-is-it-and-how-to-add-to-repo/#:%7E:text=gitignore%20file%20is%20a%20text,all%20of%20your%20Git%20repositories).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
The thing is that gitignore ignore it for git, but vscode still find and use it on startup. I also tried to hide it on vscode but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The folder opened by VS Code is used as the workspace, so please open the folder of the Java project correctly. it will identify the java project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I opened the folder that was open in Eclipse as well, it doesn't have directly the .java files but it's just inside a folder inside the workspace, i don't really get how vscode don't understand it's a java project when 90% of the files are .java. 

Maybe i don't really understand what a "Java project" actually is? Is there some files that are needed on the opened folder ?